# CakePHP - pass an empty value into a radio button

Tags: cakephp, radio-button

How can I pass an empty value to a radio button in Cake?

I've looked into Cake's 2.0 helpers form documentation but I didn't seem to find much about this.

Maybe some of you can enlighten me?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

FormHelper::**radio**(*string $fieldName, array $options, array $attributes*)

Creates a set of radio button inputs.

```
$options = array('M' => 'Male');
$attributes = array('legend' => false);
echo $this->Form->radio('gender', $options, $attributes);
```

Will output:

```
<input name="data[User][gender]" id="UserGender_" value="" type="hidden" />
<input name="data[User][gender]" id="UserGenderM" value="M" type="radio" />
```

> If for some reason you don’t want the hidden input, setting
>   $attributes['value'] to a selected value or boolean false will do just
>   that.

As you can see on the documentation of [FormHelper::radio](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::radio)

Comment: The thing is that I already have a radio button and I am not looking into adding another one. I want - if it's possible - to add the empty value in the one I have.

Comment: You want to pass an empty value if radio button is not checked, I'm right?

Comment: That's what I want, yes.

Comment: The above example, when you submit the form without check radio button, its pass an empty value.

Comment: Thing is I was using `this->Form->input($fieldName, $inputOptions)` to output my radio button, where `$inputOptions` is my key => value array. To all my items returned by this, I have prepended another item using `array_unshift($items, $newItem)`, where `$newItem` has similar structure as `$inputOptions`. I want to pass that empty value to `$newItem`. Could I do this in the way you showed me above?